# Update the records along with duplicates using upsert_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The issue I am facing is I want to update several fields for all records/visits with unique values i.e; all the values being added should be different for each one and even if a duplicate record/visit comes I need to update it as well with a different value compared to its duplicate. I am using rails `6.1` and ruby `2.7.5`. I tried using `upsert_all` but it skips the duplicate ones. I am using Postgres for the DB. The code I attempted is as follows -

```
visit_hash = @filtered_visits.where(record_id: nil).map.with_index do |visit, idx|
      {
        approval_status: visit.approval_status,
        comment: visit.comment,
        ends_at: visit.ends_at,
        mileage: visit.mileage,
        note: visit.note,
        batch_id: visit.batch_id,
        client_id: visit.client_id,
        employee_id: visit.employee_id,
        parent_visit_id: visit.parent_visit_id,
        provider_id: visit.provider_id,
        service_id: visit.service_id,
        record_id: idx + 1
      }
    end
    Visit.upsert_all(
      visit_hash,
      unique_by: [:record_id]
    )
```

If I try using `visit.id` in unique_by it fails with an error for violating the unique constraint. I want to update all the visits `record_id` with the number of visits as they occur, like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... I've been stuck for this since hours trying to figure out.

My table for visit looks like this -

```
        Column         |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 id                    | uuid                           |           | not null | gen_random_uuid()
 clocked_in_at         | timestamp without time zone    |           |          | 
 clocked_out_at        | timestamp without time zone    |           |          | 
 ends_at               | timestamp without time zone    |           |          | 
 starts_at             | timestamp without time zone    |           |          | 
 address_id            | uuid                           |           |          | 
 client_id             | uuid                           |           | not null | 
 employee_id           | uuid                           |           |          | 
 provider_id           | uuid                           |           | not null | 
 service_id            | uuid                           |           |          | 
 note                  | text                           |           |          | 
 created_at            | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at            | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 visit_services_count  | integer                        |           |          | 0
 visit_tasks_count     | integer                        |           |          | 0
 express               | boolean                        |           |          | false
 approval_status       | integer                        |           |          | 
 service_allotment_id  | uuid                           |           |          | 
 parent_visit_id       | uuid                           |           |          | 
 unbillable_hours      | numeric                        |           |          | 0.0
 sub_visits_count      | integer                        |           |          | 0
 mileage               | double precision               |           |          | 0.0
 comment               | character varying              |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "visits_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_visits_on_address_id" btree (address_id)
    "index_visits_on_client_id" btree (client_id)
    "index_visits_on_employee_id" btree (employee_id)
    "index_visits_on_parent_visit_id" btree (parent_visit_id)
    "index_visits_on_provider_id" btree (provider_id)
    "index_visits_on_service_allotment_id" btree (service_allotment_id)
    "index_visits_on_service_id" btree (service_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_1719c00c25" FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES users(id)
    "fk_rails_3c1ca25693" FOREIGN KEY (service_allotment_id) REFERENCES service_allotments(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "visit_goals" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_a72f726d0d" FOREIGN KEY (visit_id) REFERENCES visits(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `unique_by` is supposed to identify the unique index on the DB table that you want to trigger an `UPDATE` (instead of a skip).  That update would be updating all the OTHER columns in that row, they would not be updating the `unique_by` field because that's the one field that is governing the "duplicate vs new" decision.

You should be able to use `unique_by: [:id]` (or just `unique_by: :id`) and get what you want, but perhaps there's some other unique index your update/insert is violating.

Hope that helps, but if not let me know what the constraint error you're getting is with the `:id`, and also give me the `\d visits` (from `psql`) for your table.

Comment: I am getting `PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_visits_on_record_id"
DETAIL:  Key (record_id)=(1) already exists.` error upon trying this solution,

Comment: You didn't add the `\d visits` as requested.  Based on what you're saying you're using that field for it makes no sense to have a unique constraint on it.

Comment: My bad. Gimme a minute. I'll post it.

Comment: Added the result of `\d visits`

Comment: Umm, why is there no `record_id` column?  And no `index_visits_on_record_id`?

Comment: Your Rails app is pointing at a different DB than the one you pulled that from, maybe you have an older DB with that broken index in it?

Comment: That might be the case. I'd need to reset the DB and see if it helps.

Comment: This is all I get even after resetting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247230/discussion-between-smathy-and-maxagno3).

Comment: Sure. We can continue in chat.